# Swift 2/Xcode 7, 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Must translate autoResizing mask into constraints to have _setHostsLayoutEngine:YES.

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift2

I am Using Swift 2 and Version 7.0.1.
When i am navigating to TableView i am facing below error.

**Error Below**

ContactPLUS[1851:47611] *** Assertion failure in -[ContactPLUS.ResultCell _setHostsLayoutEngine:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3505.16/NSLayoutConstraint_UIKitAdditions.m:2896
2015-10-07 20:06:55.321 ContactPLUS[1851:47611] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Must translate autoresizing mask into constraints to have _setHostsLayoutEngine:YES.'

---

### Code below

var resultCell: ResultCell!
 resultCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ResultCell",   forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ResultCell

I have upgraded to Xcode 7.0.1 and getting this error.
Some of the solutions are suggesting to untick auto layout option but it is not good solution.

i am attaching the image for the references.

Can someone please siggest some solutions which works in Xcode 7.0.1 and Swift 2?

[image]

[image]

Comment: is any one having the solutions for the above?

Answer (score 0):

In my case. aftr quiting Xcode and run a few times. It works properly.